# onHover change image when using image map

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I would like to change image onHover when using imagemap(tag)

Here are my HTML and related CSS:

```css
.onetest {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('../images/circle/a.png');
}
.onetest:hover {
  z-index: 50;
  background: url('../images/circle/b.png');
}
```

```html
<img style="margin-left: 55px; margin-top: 20px;" src="images/circle/a.png" usemap="#123">
<map name="123" id="123">
  <area class="onetest" href="#" shape="polygon" coords="286,89,504,31,504,134,338,180" />
</map>
```

What I want to do is that when I hover a specific area on the image, the image would change to another.

Comment: Can you provide some demo like on https://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Don't quite understand what exactly you want to achieve, but take a look at `jquery.imagemapster` plugin